# pexpect child.before is empty when output is more than 2000 lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect

I'm using the pexpect module with Python3.4 to automate a few commands in a junos router.
I'm successfully able to get into the router and execute the commands. However I want to save the output of the command `show configuration | display sets | no more` in a `child.before` variable, but it's empty. `Child.before` is getting populated properly if the output is only a few lines. But here, the output is around 2000 lines long.

The code I used is:

```
self.child.sendline('show configuration | display set | no-more')
self.child.expect('>')
output = self.child.before
print(output)
```

Output is returning empty if the command returns a large number of lines.
I checked if there is a max read which I can set but even that didn't help me out.

Can someone show me what can be done here?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to cat a file with 128k lines with no issues via `pexpect` and `Child.before`. I think your problem does not lie with pexpect.

Comment: pexpect doesn't do pipes - its only waiting for the first command to complete - but you can use a subshell to do the work. I don't have csh, but I think this should do it: `self.child.sendline('csh -t "show configuration | display set | no-more"')`. If this does it, let me know and I'll make it the answer.

Comment: @cziemba: In my case the output of command : " show configuration | display set | no-more" will have around 2000 lines. This command is being executed in junos prompt via pexpect. I can see the output in logfile but nothing comes in print(output)

Comment: @tdelaney: "csh -t" is not a valid junos command. pipes are part of junos command itself. So pipes are allowed and it's for junos not pexpect.

Comment: same code works when the configuration is less around 15 lines. So I definitely feel it's something to do with pexpect

Comment: could you reproduce it using by running `sys.executable` that prints many lines using `pexpect`?

Comment: Hi, is there any tutorial for beginners on how to launch qemu with any router?

Answer (score 0):

`pexpect` can read more than `2000` lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pexpect  # $ pip install pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn(sys.executable, ['-c', """
for i in range(4000): # print lines
    print(str(i) * 200)
print('>')
print('end')
"""])
child.expect(b'>')
print(len(child.before.splitlines()))
# -> 4000
```